# handle input for cli using child_process nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, command-line, child-process

[image]

i want to make cli commend using node,

- first i enter commed helium-wallet create basic --seed mobile --output ./wallet-mobile.key
- both commeds need input key

how do i make this code in nodejs?

i have tried to create using exec but i don't know how to input key after the first commend is executed

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to produce a wallet with nodejs, there are other packages, after compiling the "blockchain-node" project, you can send http://127.0.0.1:4467 request to it.